# Cannot connect to sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I cannot connect to Sql server remotely from management studio , It is corrrect User name and password, but

how to enable remote connections to a sql server?
what is other chances?

Cannot connect to xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx

===================================

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out surface area configuration. It gives options to do so.

Edit: Enable the Named pipes conenction as well. I guess you are using Named pipe to connect. Also check if the SQL server browser service is running on the DB server.

Comment: Nop, it allows remote connection on TCP\IP

Answer (score 0):

Check the Authentication mode settings. It may be set to Windows Authentication only, it needs to be in Mixed Mode to accept SQL usernames & passwords.

Also check the Server network configuration and make sure named pipes or tcp/ip are enabled add that the client is using the appropriate protocol.

Comment: does the Server have a firewall?

Answer (score 0):

If everythings are correct, you may want to connect with a upper version, for example you are in SQL Server 2005 and want to connect to SQL Server 2008.

Note that you cannot connect to a upper version.(only same version or older version are granted)